# Why do I need to use CSS classes with polymer?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

For some reason this isn't working

`<body fullbleed>`

But this is

`<body class="fullbleed">`

What am I doing wrong? I'm guessing that I forgot to import something, but I can't quite figure out what. I built the project using [generator-angular](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-polymer).

Comment: See [this](http://jcrowther.io/2015/06/01/upgrading-from-polymer-v0-5-v1-0/) migration guide. In particular the styling section. In previous versions of  polymer, the layout was done using attributes. These have now been moved to CSS classes.

Comment: Ben Thomas answered my question. I missed that the documentation I was looking at was for 0.5, while I was working on 1.0.